# Giving PHP write permission in Apache

Tags: php, apache2, httpd.conf, apache2.2

I'm relatively new to configuring Apache.

I have a PHP script that writes a JSON file based on values retrieved from `$_GET`.

```
<?php

    file_put_contents('State.json', "{ do: '" . $_GET['do'] . "' }");

    echo "Success";

?>
```

I run that code by create an XHR request.

```
Ally.xhr('/Cream/Foam?do=someCommand');
```

The page it returns says `failed to open stream: Permission denied on line 3.`

```
<Directory "~/Dropbox/Web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    AllowOverride None

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Those are the permissions given to the root server folder.

What do I need to change to allow PHP to write the file?

(I have pretty much no idea what the block above means.)

Comment: What about the chmod permissions of the file/directory it is writing to?

Comment: No very good idea to put a webfolder to the root folder. Put it to /var/www/ like the other files. There you have no problems with the rights.

Comment: ..chmod? I have no idea what that is. Maybe that's what I'm missing.

Comment: chmod is a POSIX function to set the use mode permissions (ch-change mod-mode). If you use FTP, you can see how these are done.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to check if the user under which runs apache has permission to write into the directory.

So it's like this:

Your apache server is process. The process runs under some user (say www). The PHP runs under apache. So if you try to write into a directory in PHP it is the same as if the user www logs into the server and tries to create a file in the same directory. So check who is owner of that directory and which permission do it have. You can do it e.g. via `ls -la` command. If `www` will be owner of that directory, you will be 100% safe ...

Comment: It runs under the default _www. So if I give it permission this should work?

Comment: chown www-data:www-data ~/Dropbox/Web and chmod 777 ~/Dropbox/Web

Comment: Please don't chmod 777 anything on your public-facing web server.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the permissions with

[chmod](http://php.net/manual/de/function.chmod.php) function for php and set your directory to /var/www there you have normally enough permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file permission either in command line using:

```
ls -l /path/filename
```

Or through your ftp client if you have ftp access to the file/dir. If not, you could change the location like Stony said above.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file/directory permissions that it is trying to write to.  Make sure that it is writable by the user and/or group that the Apache process is running as.

Also check to see if SELinux is enabled by checking the contents of /selinux/enforce.  If it is, either disable it or make sure the proper labels are set on the path that you are writing to.

Answer (score 0):

Know that sometimes there is absolutely no way to get around this using PHP only.

The two solutions to this are:

1. Configure PHP and Apache permissions manually (warning: can get dirty very quickly).
2. Use FTP to change ownership to 0777 (full access) and then revert after running changes.

I've often found the latter option to work best.