# PHP file_put_contents failed to open stream

Tags: php

So the PHP program is supposed to take the user input and save it in a text file called "guest_list" but I am getting these error messages:

> Warning: file_put_contents(guest_list.txt): failed to open stream:
>   Permission denied in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/lecture2/welcome.php on line 44
>
> Warning: file_put_contents(guest_list.txt): failed to open stream:
>   Permission denied in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/lecture2/welcome.php on line 45
>
> Warning: file_put_contents(guest_list.txt): failed to open stream:
>   Permission denied in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/lecture2/welcome.php on line 46
>
> Warning: file_put_contents(guest_list.txt): failed to open stream:
>   Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/lecture2/welcome.php on line 47

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Code Part 1]

[image: Code Part 2]

Comment: Have you made sure that it has read/write access to the file in question?

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: By learning some Linux

Comment: You get "*Permission denied*", so that file doesn't have write-access. If you do `echo fileperms($file);`, what code do you get back? And btw, next time - please don't post images of code. Code is text, and we like it that way. :-)

Comment: You could look at PHP CHMOD as an alternative to change permissions to the file if it exists (not recommended): http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: Sorry, I tried to but I kept getting format errors. Anyway I got "33188" when I threw it in my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Giving PHP write permission in Apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357781/giving-php-write-permission-in-apache)