# Save Contact Form's Messages in Server

Tags: php

How to save contact form's messages in server? 
I used PHP to save messages, but it doesn't work and got an "`HTTP ERROR 405`" error.

My HTML code:

```
<body>
<form action="contact.php" method="POST">
    <p>Name</p><input type="text" name="name">
    <p>Email</p><input type="text" name="email">
    <p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
</body>
```

My PHP Code

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$myfile = fopen("textfile.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $name);
fwrite($myfile, $email);
fwrite($myfile, $message);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Or is there an easier way to save messages in server?

Comment: that is probably the easiest (and least practical) way to store data on teh server. the problem is your server is not configured to handle POST requests. Either enable POST or use GET instead.

Comment: HTTP 405 errors are "method not allowed". What kind of a host are you running on?

Comment: @j08691 It's just a local live server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved after the following process.

1. Re-install LAMP ([instruction video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vazRx1Ei8VA))
2. Modified the apache2.conf file ([instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all))
   set AllowOverride of the directory /var/www
3. Change the permission for /var/www/html folder ([instruction1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791485/how-do-i-save-php-file-in-var-www-html-when-it-shows-error-permission-denied), [instruction2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357781/giving-php-write-permission-in-apache))
4. Put your html and php files in the /var/www/html folder

Finally, go to http://localhost/contact.html, the contact form can save messages in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

405 Method Not Allowed is shown because **POST** is not supported by your server.
Try GET method

```
<body>
<form action="contact.php" method="GET">
    <p>Name</p><input type="text" name="name">
    <p>Email</p><input type="text" name="email">
    <p>Messages</p><textarea name="messages" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
</body>
```

php

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$message = $_GET['message'];
$myfile = fopen("messages.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $name);
fwrite($myfile, $email);
fwrite($myfile, $message);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: I can use the GET method, but it doesn't save messages in the message.txt file.