# Symfony 3.4 Apache Permission WebServer unable to write file in folder non writable

Tags: apache, symfony, chmod, chown

I'm running Symfony using Apache WebServer instead of built-in webserver, in order to switch from dev to production environment, following theses official instructions:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

When I try to upload an image to my site folder I got

```
Unable to write in the 
"/var/www/html/site/src/../public/front/cms/explanatory_rubric" directory
```

When I was running using Symfony built in server, using the port 8000 it was working and my folder was writable.
I know it's a trouble with Apache Permissions. There are a lot of questions about that and I read carefully each of them, specially [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa&newreg=8b165e2f355c4b6abb8ff6bc69c2f0d7), explaining good practices about file permissions with Apache,and [this one](https://www.g-loaded.eu/2008/12/09/making-a-directory-writable-by-the-webserver/), [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41241/how-to-check-which-apache-group-i-can-use-for-the-web-server-to-write), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357781/giving-php-write-permission-in-apache?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa),and [this one](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/apache/setting-permissions-in-apache/), etc

When I check my chmod owner non-writable folder I get:

```
ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 root www-data 4096 Jun  1 11:38 explanatory_rubric
```

I changed the chmod owner of the folder from www-data to root to give a 
write permission.

I also tried to give permission via my Apache configuration file.

This is my Apache configuration for SSL:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName www.mysite.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html/site/public>
         AllowOverride All
         Order Allow,Deny
         Allow from All
    </Directory>


    <Directory /var/www/html/site/public/front/cms/explanatory_rubric>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
```

Comment: HI, I believe Apache always use www-data as user when visiting an application through a browser so www-data needs to have write acces to your application folder.

Comment: Ok, so I have to declare the directory in my Apache configuration ? Why my configuration is actually not working to give write access to the folder ? Thanks for support

Answer (score 1):

Solved:
I updated chown from ubuntu to www-data, and I give the chmod permission to the specific folders:
I noticed also that in **index.php** from **symfony/apache-pack** pack we can
find a **umask(000)** which can may be the origin of my troubles

My command to solve it was:

```
chown www-data:www-data -R /my/folder # with Apache2
chown apache:apache -R /my/folder # with Apache
chmod -R 777 /my/folder
```